# Can't find the error in my calculation of $\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{1}{2}}(1+x^2)}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

I know $$\int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( 1+x^2 \right)} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}.$$  I want to calculate this integral using complex analysis.  So I want to integrate $$ \frac{1}{z^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( 1+z^2 \right)} $$ over the contour consisting of two semicircles in the upper half plane centered at the origin, one of radius $R >> 1$ and one of radius $\delta << 1$, traveling counterclockwise along the larger semicircle; the two semicircles are attached in the obvious way along the real axis.  To accommodate this integral and contour, I need to choose the branch of $\log$ defined by \begin{align} \log(re^{ix}) = \ln(r) + ix, && r > 0, && -\frac{\pi}{2} < x <\frac{\pi}{2}. \end{align}

The integral vanishes along the two semicircles as $R \to \infty$ and $\delta \to 0$.  And one can calculate that $$2\pi i \cdot \text{Res}(i) = 2\pi i \cdot -\frac{e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}}{2} = \pi e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}. $$  By the Residue Theorem, this is equal to $$\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{dz}{z^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( 1+z^2 \right)} + \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( 1+x^2 \right)}.$$  Calculating the integral on the left in reverse, i.e. using $z = \gamma(x) = -x$, gives $$ - \int_0^\infty \frac{-dx}{(-x)^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( 1 + x^2 \right)} \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (*). $$  Since $(-x)^{\frac{1}{2}} = ix^{\frac{1}{2}}$ this becomes $$ -i \int_0^\infty \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{1}{2}} \left( 1 + x^2 \right)}.$$  The calculation seems therefore to be giving the integral as $$\frac{\pi e^{-\frac{\pi i}{4}}}{1 - i} $$ which is not real.  (EDIT:  Yes it is!  And equal to $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$, as desired.)

In fact, if it were a $1 + i$ instead of a $1 - i$, then I would have the desired answer $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.  **But alas I cannot get that negative sign to switch.**  I've gone over it a few times closely, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong; the error seems to be something with the parametrization $(*)$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all correct basically, as far as I can see you just did something strange right at the end.  We have
$$e^{-\pi i/4}=\frac{1-i}{\sqrt2}$$
so
$$\frac{\pi e^{-\pi i/4}}{1-i}=\frac\pi{\sqrt2}\ .$$

Comment: yep yep yep.  Late night shenanigans, I suppose...In my head I was multiplying by $1-i$ instead of dividing.  Thanks!